# PHP File Parsing With Multiple Files

Tags: php, parsing

I dont want to run WordPress or other CMS. I would rather write simple text files with tages to delimitate data and use SFTP to upload. My page then parses the text files to displat when someone hits the page.

My format is similar to HTML (and I can modify my format to what works best). My format is:

```
(##DATE##)05/11/2011(##DATE##)
(##TITLE##)title of post(##TITLE##)
(##SUMMARY##)summary of the post(##SUMMARY##)
(##POST##) the entire post(##POST##)
(##AUTHOR##)the author(##AUTHOR##)
```

One catch is I want the first 5 posts in a directory of posts to be parsed only. The rest I can parse on demand when the user wants to view the post.

Can anyone shed some light on the best way to parse the first 10 files (according to file date) into the above format so I can display?

Comment: why are you not using a standard data format like XML or JSON?

Comment: Why did you invent a new format ? Can't you use JSON e.g ? Then you could use existing libraries to parse your JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any database, you should use XML as it is a web-standard and PHP provides support for reading and writing it.

But if you want to do things like "Show only 10 articles" or "Show only the Article withe ID/Date of XY", a Text or XML-file is simply very slow because the parser needs to read every entry and determine if it is the desired entry or not. In this case, a Database like MySQL is the better way.